# Centering an align environment on the page?

Tags: amsmath

I am finding that some of my AMS math `align` environments can sometimes be flushed left in a displeasing way:

[image]

The first equation is typeset using `$$`, the second series of equations is typeset using `align`. How do I "center" the align environment so it sits nicely like the display math stuff?

Comment: Do you have the `fleqn` option for your documentclass?

Comment: you should not use `$$` in latex. If you used the latex syntax `\[  \]`  then single line equations and aligned displays will use the same formatting, both centred or both flush left, depending on the package options you use.

Comment: @Bernard no, as I don't know what that is! Let me look into it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I see! Let me try this out.

Comment: Please show the code that gives rise to the screeshot you posted.

Comment: @Mico ok, I will do so! It will take me a bit, so I will do it later today once I am done more pressing tasks.